# What AI technique or something else should I use on this logic problem?

Tags: algorithm

for didactic purposes I'm trying to complete this challenge:
A random 3 digit number is generated (1-9) the Char sequence is DESC, for exemple "123" is a invalid number generated cause 1 > 2 and 2 > 3; 
"321" is valid.

when you try to guess the number it returns C for correct Char in exact placement  and N for correct Char in wrong placement, eg:

```
randomly generated "961"
algorithm try "321" and XPTO returns C = 1 and N = 0
algorithm try "654" and XPTO returns C = 0 and N = 1
```

The objective is get C=3 efficiently with less tries as possible, don't even know what kind of AI technique I need to learn about, Any tip or recommendation?

Comment: this is a simpler version of mastermind, perhaps you can use similar ideas from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/546/clever-ways-to-solve-mastermind)

Comment: Awesome, now I have a entry point, tyvm @juvian

Answer (score 0):

After the hint of @juvian I built an js solution

First create a List:

```
function generateList(){
List = new Array();
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) { 
for (j = i+1; j <= 8; j++) { 
for (k = j+1; k <= 9; k++) { 
List.push(""+k+j+i);}}}
WriteResult(List.length,List[0]);
}
```

Then make the tests and exclude from List the "not possible" combinations

```
for( var i = List.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ 
var C = Number(document.getElementById("C").value);
var N = Number(document.getElementById("N").value);
var Guess = ""+Number(document.getElementById("Guess").value);
var CountC = 0
var CountN = 0

for( var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
if (Guess.substr(j, 1) == List[i].substr(j, 1)) {CountC++;}
else if (List[i].split(Guess.substr(j, 1)).length > 1) {CountN++;}
}
console.log(List[i]+" C:"+CountC+" N:"+CountN);
if (CountC != C || CountN != N) {List.splice(i, 1); }
}  
WriteResult(List.length,List[0]); 
}
```